# Safely clearing Hibernate session in the middle of large transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm

I am using Spring+Hibernate for an operation which requires creating and updating literally hundreds of thousands of items. Something like this:

```
{
   ...
   Foo foo = fooDAO.get(...);
   for (int i=0; i<500000; i++) {
      Bar bar = barDAO.load(i);
      if (bar.needsModification() && foo.foo()) {
         bar.setWhatever("new whatever");
         barDAO.update(bar);
         // commit here
         Baz baz = new Baz();
         bazDAO.create(baz);
         // if (i % 100 == 0), clear
      }
   }
}
```

To protect myself against losing changes in the middle, I commit the changes immediately after `barDAO.update(bar)`:

```
HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = ...; // injected by Spring
DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED);
TransactionStatus transactionStatus = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);
transactionManager.commit(transactionStatus);
```

At this point I have to say that entire process is running in a transaction wrapped into `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.ExtendedOpenSessionInViewFilter` (yes, this is a webapp).

This all works fine with one exception: after few thousand of updates/commits, entire process gets really slow, most likely due to memory being bloated by ever-increasing amount of objects kept by Spring/Hibernate.

In Hibernate-only environment this would be easily solvable by calling `org.hibernate.Session#clear()`.

Now, the questions:

- When is it a good time to `clear()`? Does it have big performance cost?
- Why aren't objects like `bar` or `baz` released/GCd automatically? What's the point of keeping them in the session after the commit (in the next loop of iteration they're not reachable anyway)? I haven't done memory dump to prove this but my good feeling is that they're still there until completely exited. If the answer to this is "Hibernate cache", then why isn't the cache flushed upon the available memory going low?
- is it safe/recommended to call `org.hibernate.Session#clear()` directly (having in mind entire Spring context, things like lazy loading, etc.)? Are there any usable Spring wrappers/counterparts for achieving the same?
- If answer to the above question is true, what will happen with object `foo`, assuming `clear()` is called inside the loop? What if `foo.foo()` is a lazy-load method?

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: I am also doing multiple large inserts. Adding code to flush and clear the session occasionally just made my code run 4x faster!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> When is it a good time to `clear()`? Does it have big performance cost?

At regular intervals, ideally the same as the JDBC batch size, after having flushed the changes. The documentation describes common idioms in the chapter about [Batch processing](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html):

> #### [13.1. Batch inserts](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-inserts)
>
> When making new objects persistent
> flush() and then clear() the session
> regularly in order to control the size
> of the first-level cache.
>
> ```
> Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
> Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
>    
> for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
>     Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
>     session.save(customer);
>     if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
>         //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
>         session.flush();
>         session.clear();
>     }
> }
>    
> tx.commit();
> session.close();
> ```

And this shouldn't have a performance *cost*, au contraire:

- it allows to keep the number of objects to track for dirtiness low (so flushing should be fast),
- it should allow to reclaim memory.

> Why aren't objects like `bar` or `baz` released/GCd automatically? What's the point of keeping them in the session after the commit (in the next loop of iteration they're not reachable anyway)?

You need to `clear()` the session explicitly if you don't want to keep entities tracked, that's all, that's how it works (one might want to commit a transaction without "losing" the entities).

But from what I can see, `bar` and `baz` instances should become candidate to GC after the clear. It would be interesting to analyze a memory dump to see what is happening exactly.

> is it safe/recommended to call `org.hibernate.Session#clear()` directly

As long as you `flush()` the pending changes to not lose them (unless this is what you want), I don't see any problem with that (your current code will lose a create every 100 loops, but maybe it's just some pseudo code).

> If answer to the above question is true, what will happen with object `foo`, assuming `clear()` is called inside the loop? What if `foo.foo()` is a lazy-load method?

Calling [`clear()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#clear%28%29) evicts all loaded instances from the [`Session`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html), making them detached entities. If a subsequent invocation requires an entity to be "attached", it will fail.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to point out that, after clearing the session, if you want to continue to use some objects that were in the session, you will have to `Session.refresh(obj)` them in order to continue.

Otherwise you will get following error:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException
```