# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion)

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm receiving the following error while using session.clear() in my batch transaction with hibernate.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion)
```

I'm using the following code

```
    try {
        for (TimeSheetEntity timeSheet : timeSheets) {
            timeSheet.setActive(false);
            try {
                session.update(timeSheet);

                count++;

                if (count % 250 == 0 || totalCount == count) {
                    System.out.println(count);

                    session.flush();
                    session.clear();
                }
            } catch (HibernateException ex) {
                logger.error(ArchiveImpl.class.getName(), ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex) + "[" + timeSheet.getId() + "] ");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.error(ArchiveImpl.class.getName(), ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex) + "[" + timeSheet.getId() + "] ");
            }
        }

        sessionManager.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        logger.error(ArchiveImpl.class.getName(), ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
        sessionManager.abort();
    } finally {
    }
```

Now if I remove session.clear(); everything works as it's suppose to. Any ideas why I can't use clear within my batch transaction with hibernate search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `Session#flush()` flushes changes to the database.
Changes to the index managed by Hibernate Search are flushed by using `FullTextSession#flushToIndexes()`.

If you need to *clear()* your session, you should flush both of these, or some entities will still be enqueued for indexing but won't be managed anymore, which is a problem.

Hibernate Search won't automatically flush to indexes when you do a flush to database, as a flush to the indexes will not be undone in case you abort the transaction, so it's better if you decide explicitly which one (or both) of the flushes you want to happen.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for, worked perfectly thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your call to `session.clear();` is within the for loop. If you want to close the session, do that after the loop has ended.

Comment: That doesn't entirely make sense to me, if you don't call session.clear in the for loop, you run the risk of an out of memory exception. Session.clear() should be just clearing the L1 cache, not closing the session right? I have other apps where I do this exact same thing and I have no issues. The only thing I can think of is perhaps relational tables that are being lazy loaded might be the culprit? Example of a batch insert http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788048/safely-clearing-hibernate-session-in-the-middle-of-large-transaction

Comment: Then have you tried using a transaction for your update operations?

Comment: Yes, this is handled by the frameworks session manager http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/hibernate/HibernateSessionManager.html