# Does an EntityManager hold references to detached entities?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, garbage-collection

Running in some memory limitations when using JPA (Hibernate) I was looking for some information on how the EntityManager deals with detached entities, especially whether he keeps any strong references to them.

I was searching through the general JPA documentation as well as through the Hibernate documentation but couldn't find any specific information? From what I got EntityManager.clear() will detach all entities and make them available for garbage collection. Does this imply that detaching an entity from the EntityManager makes it available for the garbage collector? If not, how to make a specific entity managed by an Entitymanager available for GC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detached entity is not referenced by Hibernate. It may be indirectly referenced by Hibernate if it is referenced by a managed entity instance, but after clearing the session, there will be no managed instances.

Actually, clearing the session to free memory is an official and documented pattern for [batch processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788048/safely-clearing-hibernate-session-in-the-middle-of-large-transaction).

Comment: Clearning the entire EntityManager/ Hibernate session is not an possible for me (unfortunately).